# iTextSharp filling an existing pdf but the multiline text field won't wrap

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I have a PDF I created/edit in Adobe Acrobat Pro 2017. The goal is to fill it out dynamically on our website. It is successful for all but one part; one of the form fields won't wrap the text as expected.

```cs
    var TheForm = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(TheDocument, true);
    var Fields = TheForm.GetFormFields();

    //* just trying some stuff, it didn't pan out
    //Fields["MyField"].SetFieldFlag(PdfTextFormField.FF_MULTILINE).SetFontSizeAutoScale();

    //#This set the value correctly, but it doesn't wrap
    Fields["MyField"].SetValue("Field Office Wide - Fuelwood");

    //# proof the field is multiline, this is true in debugging
    var helpme = Fields["MyField"].IsMultiline();   

    //# proof the field is set correctly, just the display won't wrap
    var grrrrr = Fields["MyField"].GetValue();

    //# make the PDF read-only and remove the form fields
    TheForm.FlattenFields();
```

Here is the PDF form output as I manually type in it with Acrobat Reader 2017

[image]

And here is the output of the code

[image]

Here is a hopefully anonymized version of the file
https://github.com/Wyseguys/wyseguys.github.io/blob/Wyseguys-patch-1/form.pdf  (Its not a big secret or anything, just staying quiet)

Also, this might be a related question, and I am exploring this now
[Text not fitting into form fields (iTextSharp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477522/text-not-fitting-into-form-fields-itextsharp)

Comment: Please share the PDF in question to allow reproducing the issue. Or, if it's confidential, create another one containing just the problem field identical as in your problem PDF.

Comment: @mkl thank you.  I added a link.

Comment: I'll look into that early next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iText 7 does not determine a font size yet for which the whole text fits the form field:

```
/// <summary>Adjust font in case autosize.</summary>
private float GetFontSize(PdfArray bBox, String value) {
    if (this.fontSize == 0) {
        //We do not support autosize with multiline.
        if (IsMultiline() || bBox == null || value == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
            return DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE;
        }
        else {
            return Math.Max(ApproximateFontSizeToFitBBox(this.font, bBox.ToRectangle(), value), MIN_FONT_SIZE);
        }
    }
    return this.fontSize;
}
```

*(`PdfFormField` helper method)*

(As you see, `DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE` is used as font size. This value is defined as `12`.)

In particular iText 7 does not support the **DoNotScroll** form field flag you have set on your form field.

As a result the text "Field Office Wide - Fuelwood" is split into two lines. As the field widget appearance stream contains a clip path along the field widget border, though, you see only the first line. This clip path also lets you see only the first line in the flattened view but you can navigate the cursor into the second line and select the text there.

To fill multiline fields, therefore, set their font size to a value that likely will do the job, i.e. allow all your likely inputs to fit into the widget area. Alternatively, if you have no control over the PDF forms, remove the **Multiline** flag just before filling to make iText autosize into a single line.

Comment: I hate it when the answer is such a short thing.  This nailed it.  I edited the form in Adobe and unchecked the "multiline" box for those fields.  The font (which I never set a size for) correctly adjusted when it flattened.  Thank you so much.